# Symfony 3 + Homestead-7: Trailing slash after app_dev.php access denied

Tags: vagrant, symfony, homestead

I've encountered a problem when using Symfony 3 on Homestead-7. I didn't see any questions about this here, so I just wanted to post this incase anyone might run into the same problem.

## **The problem**

When running app_dev.php with a trailing slash, I get “Access Denied.” But using it without trailing slash works just fine. For example:

```
http://sandbox.local/app_dev.php/?page=2
```

Gives:

```
Access Denied.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## **The solution**

In this file:

```
~/Homestead/scripts/serve-symfony2.sh
```

I've replaced this:

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)\$;
```

with:

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)\$;
```

For both DEV and PROD environments.
Afterwards I ran:

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

Problem solved!